# Why my On-demand ISR in Nextjs is not working?

Tags: next.js

I'm revalidating this page in the `pages/api/revalidate.js` file.
But I receive the next error: `Error: Failed to revalidate /blog/conquest-slovenia-adventure-challenge: Invalid response undefined`;

This is my code:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    try {
        await res.unstable_revalidate('/blog/conquest-slovenia-adventure-challenge');
        return res.json({ revalidated: true });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
}
```

I just updated my nextjs version to ^12.1.4.

Comment: Does the `/blog/conquest-slovenia-adventure-challenge` page actually exist? Has the page been statically generated before you tried to revalidate it?

Comment: You have your error in API route, not in your code shown

Comment: Yes, it was already created. The problem was that I was missing a final '/' in the url

Comment: @Turkex Lifesaver!